# Two fair dice tossed simultaneously till combination $(4,3)$ is obtained. Obtain the probability that number of tosses required is atmost $2$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, game-theory, dice

**Original Question:** Two fair dice are tossed simultaneously till a combination $(4,3)$ is obtained. Obtain the probability that the number of tosses required is atmost $2$.

**My Reasoning** : The dice are thrown simultaneously. One can't determine or distinguish between the two die. Thus, the combination of $(4,3)$ will **include** the outcomes $(4,3)$ as well as $(3,4)$.  With that reasoning, I came up with following solution:

$$x : \text{Number of tosses required to obtain the combination} $$
$$x ~ \text{~ Geometric distribution}\left(p=\frac{2}{36}=\frac{1}{18}\right)  $$
$$P(x < 3) = P(x = 1) + P(x = 2)  = \left(1-\frac{1}{18}\right)^0*\left(\frac{1}{18}\right) + \left(1-\frac{1}{18}\right)^1*\left(\frac{1}{18}\right) = 0.108025$$

But this answer was not accepted. Can someone please point out how is the reasoning wrong?

The answer expected was $0.0547839$ with p = $\frac{1}{36}$. Does order matters?

Comment: Well, you assumed that if we can't tell the difference between $(4,3)$ and $(3,4)$ they have to be considered the same.  The answer states $p=\frac 1{36}$ that they *are* to be considered distinct. It's not a fair or clearly worded question in my opinion.  But consider this analogy.  A classmate of Bart Simpson's is picked at random.  What is the probability that is it Terry (the identical twin sister of Sherry).  We argue, well we can't tell the difference between Terry and Sherry so we have to assume either one of them is the same thing as Terry.... is that valid?

Comment: Neither answer is wrong and which one is right depends on what question is *actually* being asked.  The books answer is the correct answer to the question "what is the probability it takes at most two rolls to get a four on the green die and a 3 on the red die".  Your answer is the correct on to "what is the probability one non specified of the dice is 4 and the other 3".  Now I think most people would think your question is the more reasonable interpretation. But... apparently the book didn't think so.  Not a good book IMO but... bad books exist.

Comment: @fleablood For the 'Twin Example', I can argue that there's one distinguishable feature which is certainly known.. that is their names! So, if the dice were named something like 'Die1' and 'Die2', then i would have agreed with that reasoning. So the example in itself is valid, but comparing it with current problem isn't..

Comment: @fleablood, yeah.. agreed; bad book exists. The question could have been more clearer/specific.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your reasoning.  You are not told the dice are distinguishable; even if they were (e.g., one die is red and the other is green), you are also not told which die represents the first outcome in the ordered pair $(4,3)$.

There could be a circumstance by which the dice are indistinguishable and do not correspond to a fixed ordering, but the outcomes $(4,3)$ and $(3,4)$ are distinguishable because of how they are read:  for instance, whichever die lands to the left of the other die corresponds to the first outcome in the pair.  If you cannot visually determine the order from left to right, you read the dice from top to bottom.

But again, this requires an interpretation of the question that is not stated.  It is much more reasonable to infer that the outcomes are indistinguishable, in which case observing one $4$ and one $3$ in a single roll is $1/18$, and observing such an outcome within at most $2$ rolls is simply $$\frac{1}{18} + \frac{17}{18^2}.$$

The only thing working in favor of distinguishable outcomes is the fact the problem wrote $(4,3)$ rather than $\{4,3\}$.  But this notational difference is inadequate:  the problem *needs* to explicitly state that the dice or their outcomes are distinguishable.  Otherwise, you would on average observe twice as many $(4,3)$ outcomes as you would $(4,4)$, and this is not reflected in the claimed answer of $\frac{71}{1296}$.

Comment: So, for the question: "When two dice are thrown simultaneously, does the order of outcome matter?" Does it matter or not?

Answer (score 2):

Remember, when two dice are tossed simultaneously,, there will be $6\times6 =36$ total **equiprobable** outcomes out of which $(4,3)$ is one and $(3,4)$ is another. (You could imagine that one die is red and the other blue, if it helps you)

Thus P(get desired outcome in at most two tosses)
= $1$- P(not get the desired outcome in two tosses)

$= 1 - (\frac{34}{36})^2$

The book is wrong.

Comment: Can You please explain how did we calculate probability of not getting the desired outcome as (34/36)^2 ?

Comment: Out of the total $36$ outcomes, we exclude the $(4,3)$ and $(3,4)$ cases so $(\frac{34}{36})^2$ is the Pr of not getting the desired outcome in $2$ tosses

Comment: Ohhh okay got it.

Comment: So, for the question: "When two dice are thrown simultaneously, does the order of outcome matter?" Does it matter or not?

Comment: @Vanquiver: If the dice look identical, you can just note that one shows a 4 and one a 3. If one is red and one blue, *again* the results are simultaneous, but in either case, the *probability* is double that of , say,  (1,1). In a sense, order matters, because if you gave a small time gap, 1st die 4, 2nd die 3, is different from 1st die 3, 2nd die 4.